# How do I deserialize a SAML assertion in Rampart/C (Axis2/C)?

Tags: saml, rampart, axis2c

I have SAML 1.1 and SAML 1.0 responses in utf-8 `char *` buffers, and I would like to transform them into Rampart/C `saml_response_t *` objects.  My question is this:

What is the correct method for creating a `saml_response_t` from a string?

Ideally I'd like a code sample in C that does this and then disposes of the various parser tools in the correct order, since Axis2/C has some odd ideas about how to free memory.

My efforts to do this have met with failure, resulting mainly in memory faults, but here's what I have.  Keep in mind that the `deserialize_buffer()` method does just what it says -- converts a buffer into an `axiom_node_t *`, but I'm open to replacing it as well.

```
/* : get the raw XML from the SAML assertion */
xml_data = Tcl_GetStringFromObj (objv[2], &xml_length);

/* : parse the response XML for processing */
stream = gstream_mem_create (xml_data, xml_length);
node = Axis2_axiom_deserialize_buffer (env, stream);

/* : build a SAML response from the parsed XML */
saml_response = saml_response_create (env);
saml_response_build (saml_response, node, env);
arraylist = saml_response_get_assertions (saml_response, env);

/* : create our return value object */
obj = Tcl_NewListObj (0, NULL);

/* :- convert the SAML assertion into a string */
for (i = 0;
     i < axutil_array_list_size (arraylist, env);
         i++) {
    saml_assertion = (saml_assertion_t *) axutil_array_list_get (arraylist, env, i);
    if (saml_assertion != NULL) {
        assertion_node = saml_assertion_to_om (saml_assertion, NULL, env);

        element = Tcl_NewStringObj (axiom_node_to_string (node, env), -1);
        Tcl_ListObjAppendElement (interp, obj, element);

        axiom_node_free_tree (assertion_node, env);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I wish I had an answer. I no longer work with SAML, nor Axis2/C. I honestly can't say I miss them.